# Communication between Galaxy S3 and NFC reader

Tags: amazon-s3, nfc, galaxy, nfc-p2p

What is the best way to communicate between Samsung Galaxy S3 and NFC reader connected to a single board computer? There are a few libraries and some NFC readers but I don't know which one is compatible with each other.

I have to send data in both directions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried yet ? please post some of your code and describe where your problem lies

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I don't have any code yet. I need to know which hardware and software I need to buy/use.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [libnfc](https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/) who is easy and powerful, if you want

For the reader, I can sugest you the [ACR122U](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U), it works great, and many peoples use it, so you can search on google if you have any problems.